# Ultrasonic sensor does not work if a relay is NC on arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, sensors

Normally the ultrasonic sensor (HC-SR04 sensor) works as expected, but when I close the relay then it stop working.

The relay is for another job, nothing related to the ping sensor yet..

This is the code:

```
/*
 * created by Rui Santos, http://randomnerdtutorials.com
 * 
 * Complete Guide for Ultrasonic Sensor HC-SR04
 *
    Ultrasonic sensor Pins:
        VCC: +5VDC
        Trig : Trigger (INPUT) - Pin11
        Echo: Echo (OUTPUT) - Pin 12
        GND: GND
 */

#define relay1 10

int trigPin = 11;    //Trig - green Jumper
int echoPin = 12;    //Echo - yellow Jumper
long duration, cm;
String cmd;

void setup() {
  //Serial Port begin
  Serial.begin (9600);

  Serial.println("Initializing Relay...");
  pinMode(relay1, OUTPUT);   

  Serial.println("Initializing Ultrasonic sensor...");
  //Define inputs and outputs
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);

}

void loop()
{ 

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // read the incoming byte:
    cmd = Serial.readString();

    if (cmd == "relayOn"){
      //relay normally closed - ultrasonic sensor stop working here
      digitalWrite(relay1, LOW);       
    }else if (cmd == "relayOff"){
      //relay normally open
      digitalWrite(relay1, HIGH);
    }
  }    

  // The sensor is triggered by a HIGH pulse of 10 or more microseconds.
  // Give a short LOW pulse beforehand to ensure a clean HIGH pulse:
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  // Read the signal from the sensor: a HIGH pulse whose
  // duration is the time (in microseconds) from the sending
  // of the ping to the reception of its echo off of an object.
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

  // convert the time into a distance
  cm = (duration/2) / 29.1;

  Serial.print(cm);
  Serial.print("cm");
  Serial.println();

  delay(250);   
}
```

EDITED: The ultrasonic sensor stop working exactly when the relay is closed, but this sensor is not connected to the relay

Comment: Why are you doing `pinMode(echoPin,INPUT)` in your main loop? You configured it in `setup()` already.

Comment: Was a mistake, I edited that

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with programming

Answer (score 0):

Use a different power supply for energizing the relay ( connect together Gnd of the two supplies), the overload may be causing the Arduino to malfunction.

Comment: Use external supply rather than through USB.  The I/O reading should not be affected by power supply.

Comment: I used an external supply, now the sensor works well but the relay does not work properly

Comment: Use the TTL voltage from Arduino to trigger a transistor like BC408 which in turn can trigger a driver transistor like SL100 to drive your relay. If you not so familiar with electronics ckt, you can use a relay board for Arduino.

Comment: I am using this relay model [Image](https://www.jaycar.com.au/medias/sys_master/images/9077167128606/arduino-compatible-5v-relay-boardImageMain-515.jpg)

Comment: That should work. But mind that it may be triggered by a logic Low. So you can accordingly adjust in your Arduino code or more easily choosing either the N/C or N/O point of the relay.

Comment: I have no idea what to change in my code, I will try to play only with the relay to see if works

Answer (score 0):

Your logic says the circuit is the issue, not the code.

Without your schematic to check, pulling the relay pin LOW to turn on looks like 
you are sourcing the relay current "thru" the relay1 pin to ground.

If so, this is a big no no.

A small relay can have as much as 100-150mA inrush current when turning on.  Large relays even more.

The Arduino pins can only handle as much as 40mA max per pin.

That would either lock it up or eventually burn out the pin or the micro itself.

Put a NPN transistor from ground to - end of the relay and use a HIGH to the transistor base to turn it on.   That way the pin is only using a few mA and the relay current passes thru the transistor.

Do not for get a blocking diode across the relay coil if it is not already in the circuit.

### there are schematics for this all over the web.

from your schematic my guess was right.  You are pulling the relay current thru the micro pin.

Look at https://www.electroschematics.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/arduino-control-relay-schematic.png  the 1K is not nessesarry and the transistor base can be on any digital pin you want pin 2 is example only.

Do include the diode across the relay coil, it blocks flyback voltage that could do damage.

The transistor will pass the relay current and isolate the micro from that current and will stop the lockup.

Any general purpose NPN transistor will work here.  Just check the pinout for wiring.

Oh by the way; with the transistor your Relay1 pin logic will be reversed, HIGH will turn on then.

Comment: Sorry for this, but I am an enthusiast in this [Schematic](http://prntscr.com/jlrs71)

Comment: from your schematic my guess was right.Your pulling the relay current thru the micro pin. -- look at https://www.electroschematics.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/arduino-control-relay-schematic.png  the 1K is not nessesarry and the transistor base can be on any digital pin you want pin 2 is example only. -- do include the diode across the relay coil, it blocks flyback voltage that could do damage. --   the transistor will pass the relay current and isolate the micro from that current and will stop the lockup.